# Edit body image after insertion in 3.9.1

Tags: tinymce

Pre 3.9.1 when I hovered over an image in the post body I was presented with 2 buttons top left of the image. One allowed me to edit the image (size, alt, title tags etc).

This has disseapred now and I can't work out how to modify the image once inserted into the body.

My functions.php

```
function formatTinyMCE($init)
{   
    $init['wpautop'] = true;
    $init['plugins'] = 'infographic';
    $init['toolbar1'] = 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,blockquote,|,link,unlink,infographic,|,bullist,numlist,|,pastetext,removeformat,|,undo,redo';
    $init['toolbar2'] = '';

    $init['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3';
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'formatTinyMCE' );
```

I tried adding `wpeditimage` to the toolbar but nothing appeared.

Comment: You shouldn't need any code, you can still do this in 3.9.1 - you just need to click the image first!

Comment: I have, there are no options, I just get a resize bounding box

Comment: Sounds like maybe a javascript error? Turn on Firebug in Firefox and see if there are any javascript errors or if some script is not being downloaded from a plugin or theme?